# bash: bin/hadoop: No such file or directory(hadoop 2.7.3 on ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, hadoop, java-home

I tried installing hadoop 2.7.3 on ubuntu 16.04 desktop.
I installed java and checked it's version as:

```
hadoop@ubuntu:~$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

I set JAVA_HOME in bashrc as:

```
#HADOOP VARIABLES START
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-i386
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/hadoop/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
```

and executed:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

then i edited the hadoop-env.sh as:

```
# The java implementation to use.
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-i386"
```

My java file location is:

[image]

then when i tried the command bin/hadoop it shows following error:

```
hadoop@ubuntu:~$ bin/hadoop
bash: bin/hadoop: No such file or directory
```

I don't know what to do.

Comment: just run `hadoop`. The path is already set to the `bin` subdir.

Answer (score 1):

These:

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/hadoop/hadoop
                          ^^^^
hadoop@ubuntu:~$ bin/hadoop
              ^
```

You're in the `~` dir (home) directory, so effectively your command is

```
/home/hadoop/bin/hadoop
```

when it should be

```
/home/hadoop/hadoop/bin/hadoop
```

aka

```
$ hadoop/bin/hadoop
```